# Getting an when I run a web app using streamlit

Tags: python, checkbox, web-applications, tabs, streamlit

After running the program I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\venv_\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Dhikrullah Muhammad\Desktop\My Documents\pythonProject\web.py", line 20, in <module>
    with tab:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Code:

```
import streamlit as st

tab = st.tabs(["My Todos"])

with tab:
    for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
        checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, key=todo)
        if checkbox:
            todos.pop(index)
            functions.write_todos(todos)
            del st.session_state[todo]
            st.experimental_rerun()
```

Expecting:
A tab named My Todos containing a list of my todos with each of them in a checkbox.

Comment: can you put the code inside ``` block and correct indent it? In order to be better readed from users.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean -Nicola Landro

Answer (score 0):

`st.tabs` returns a tuple of containers. Since you are only specifying a single tab, that's where you need an extra tweak to make sure you grab that one tab instead of the tuple of one. (The [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/layout/st.tabs#sttabs) says it's a list, but if you check it explicitly it's a tuple. Same advice either way.)

You can accomplish the needed result by explicitly taking the 0-th element or simply by adding a comma:

```
tab, = st.tabs(["My Todos"])
```

I'm not sure exactly how the rest of your code is but since you are using `pop` on a variable without some reference to session state I'm suspecting you may not get your full intended effect after resolving the referenced tab issue.